# Archive validation failed due to -[__NSArrayM objectForKey:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance

Tags: ios, xcode, validation, archive

[image: Archive validation error]

The above is the screen capture.
Running on iphone is good. But when goes to archive, the validation failed.
If I do have this kind of error in my code, it will appears when compiling. Is that right?

I tried cleaning the project and archive again. It show the same error with different instance address.

Comment: The error reveals a type mismatch: A method is sent to `NS(Mutable)Array` which belongs to `NSDictionary`.

Comment: i know that. I searched all the keyword "objectForKey" in my workspace and did not find a violation. This error does not come when compiling or running. It appears when I archive the app and validate it.

Comment: Look also for key subscripting `object["key"]` and consider that the affected object is *mutable* array.

Answer (score -1):

That looks like one of Apple's tools in the broad and opaque Validation & Upload toolchain has crashed! How strange!

This is what I would do:

1. Cmd+Option+Shift+K to clean the build folder (a pointless religious practice)
2. Quit and restart Xcode.
3. In Project Info->General set Signing to None, and then set it back to your team's identifier (or whatever you're using to sign with).
4. Archive & Submit your application again.

Good luck! If it fails again, don't hesitate to submit a bug to bugreport.apple.com.

Comment: I tried your method. The same problem. Thanks anyway and I will continue debugging...

Comment: any answer to this?